# EC(inner) calculation for a dependent query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am currently studying query optimization's and I am trying to calculate the cost of a query that has a dependent query within it.

The query is:

```
select 
    U.userName, email, yearOfBirth, countryName
from 
    tblUser U 
inner join 
    tblCountry C on U.countryNo = C.countryNo
left join 
    tblList L on U.userName = L.userName
where 
    noOfPoints = 1000 
    and yearOfBirth = 1975 
    and listNo is null 
    and not exists (select count(*)
                    from tblseek S
                    where S.userName = U.userName
                    having count(serialNo) > 3)
```

Now some data:

First of all the tables and their connections:

[image]

tblCountry: Nr=19 , Fr = 67 and Br = 1

tblUser: Nr=1,881,923, Fr = 11, Br = 171,084

tblList: Nr=4,667,166, Fr = 62, Br = 75,277

tblSeek: Nr=8,530,865, Fr = 13, Br = 656,221

The distribution among users as far as the amount of lookups for treasure is:

0 looksups: 10% of users

1 lookup: 11% of users

2 lookups: 19% of users

3 and above: 60% of users

The distribution among users as far as the amount of lists per user is:

0 lists : 30% of users

1-3 lists : 34% of users

4-6 lists: 36% of users

It is also known that the maximum amount of points in all of the system is 5200 and that it is spread uniform distribution  among the users.

And it's also known that the most young user is 16 years of age and the oldest is 57, and again the ages are spread uniform distribution  among all the users.

- Block size is : 2048 bits
- Amount of memory allocated for querying is :100 blocks
- Each table is sorted by its primary keys and if there is more than one field it is sorted in their order of their appearance in the table.

Now, what am I trying to calculate:

I am trying to determine the cost of running the dependent query before doing the joins in the outer query, hence to load tblUser to the memory and perform the inner query and then to complete the other joins.

My problem: well I figured out that in order to do that I need to load tblUser to the memory at the cost of 171,084 blocks and also to load tblSeek at the cost of 656,221 blocks, what I can't determine is how and where to perform the conditions of the "Where" clause, cause as you may notice most of the conditions in the clause are to do with attributes for tblUser(apart from the list condition).

I managed to come up with an estimation(which I am not sure is right to do and please correct me if I am wrong) of how many records would answer the "points=1000" under the uniform diversion knowlege(its 361 records) and also did the same with the "yearOfBirth = 1975"(45,900 records). I did it by dividing the Nr of tblUser with the zone of numbers that is known for the uniform diversion respectively.

I can't how ever come up with a way to combine them to one figure of how many records will come back with all the condition's mixed together(including the dependent query).

If you could guide me a bit, I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: What do Fr and Br mean?

Comment: By "blocks", do you mean 16KB InnoDB disk blocks?

Comment: I mean 100 blocks of 2048 bits(I've wrriten it). and to your question Rick Fr is the amount of records per block(which is calculated by dividing block size by record size). and Br is the amount of blocks R table takes.

Comment: "diversion" --> "division"?

Comment: i meant distribution and I just fixed it thx

Comment: Easily 90% of the cost of doing a query is I/O -- that is, unless the necessary data & indexes are already cached in RAM.  What are you assuming/measuring here?

Comment: A "covering" index leads to not needing the entire _table_, but, instead, the _index_.  This messes with your assumptions.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the cost in blocks to run the query without any index and in the way I described above, hence to load tblUser, run the dependent query and what ever from the "Where" clause of the outer query possible and then complete the outer query with what left in the where while performing the join operations specified in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` to get further insight into how the query will be performed.

Use this to get some "row counts" of the effort:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSIONS STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Indexes.  (I can't tell what you already have, since you did not provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

```
U: INDEX(yearOfBirth, noOfPoints)
```

`EXISTS(...)` is usually phrased as simply `EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )`; no need for `COUNT(*)`.  I do not understand the purpose of the `EXISTS`.  Perhaps this, which would check how many rows are in `tblseek`:

```
AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblseek WHERE userName = U.userName ) <= 3
```

Probably you want `INDEX(userName, serialNo)`, in that order.  This is a "covering" index so that the subquery can be performed entirely in the index.  `EXPLAIN` will indicate such via "Using index".

That subquery will, in total, touch every row in tblseek (or its index) once.  Actually, each scan will overshoot by one.  So the number of rows touched is likely to be N+M, where N is the number of rows in `tblseek` and M is the number of distinct values of `userName` in `tblseek`.  Without that index, the row count will be a lot higher.

Comment: I didn't provide an index cause I am trying to determine the cost of the query as it is without any indexes and run in the way I described. as far as to what the query does: it gets all the users and their details that didn't search more than 3 times and have 1000 points and born in 1975. I also gave you all the sizes of the tables(the amount of records is Nr).

Comment: At least clean up the "not exists"; I can't figure out what you intend.

Comment: I can't clear something that is part of the query cause then what's the point... the not exists part it to ensure that users with more than 3 lookups won't be returned..

Comment: But I think that is incorrect SQL to test for that.

Comment: Well, I think it hits the entire table, but I am not sure.  So, 656,221 blocks.

Comment: and what about the cost of loading tblUser? I mean to run the dependent query you need it, so is the EC(Inner) is actually 656,221+171,084 blocks?

Comment: Is there no "cache" in your model?  If not, then it does no reflect what _every_ vendor provides.

Comment: what you mean by cache? that's the first time I hear this term in this context

Comment: A database engine keeps, in RAM, as much as is practical of the tables.  This "cache" is usually on a "block" basis, and "least recently used".  Since I/O is a performance killer, so this is a significant part of the performance.  It "never" loads an entire table.